# Python, Axes3D, plotting: Cannot append to List of X,Y,Z values in my 3D scatterplot

Tags: python, axes

(Very new to python) So I've made a 3D scatterplot to which I would like to add dots of different "types". At the moment I would like to append values to X1, Y1, Z1 to create the points in question. If I type those in by hand, there doesn't seem to be any issue. However, when I try to use the append function outside of the class, the dots do not show on my plot. I would like to be able to externally append or add points on my scatterplot.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font = {'fontname': 'Franklin Gothic Demi'}
title = {'fontname': 'Bookman Old Style'}

diameter = 3500
width = 200


class world(object):


    def __init__(self):


        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
        self.ax = plt.gca()

        self.t = 0

        self.X1 = []
        self.Y1 = []
        self.Z1 = []

        self.ax.scatter(self.X1, self.Y1, self.Z1, c="r", marker="1", depthshade=True)

        self.ax.set_xlabel("synaptic diameter (nm)", color = "navy", **font)
        self.ax.set_ylabel("synaptic diameter (nm)", color = "navy", **font)
        self.ax.set_zlabel("cleft width (nm)", color = "navy", **font)

        self.ax.autoscale(enable=True)

        self.ax.set_xlim(0, diameter)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, diameter)
        self.ax.set_zlim(0, width)


        plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

        plt.title("Synapse", color = "black", size = 20, **title)


        self.Serotonin = []
        self.MAO = []
        self.immobileAgents = []
        #not yet relevant here

    def showPlot(self):

        self.showPlot = plt.show()
```

Here is (one of) the function(s) I used to append values to the lists

```
world = world()

tee = 0
while tee <= 100:

    world.X1.append(tee)
    world.Y1.append(tee)
    world.Z1.append(tee)

    tee = tee + 1

print (world.X1)
print (world.Y1)
print (world.Z1)
#just to be sure

world.showPlot()
```

Note that in this case, the prupose is merely to be able to see the dots on my plot. Their placement doesn't matter at all yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you plot when you create a world (eg. `earth=world()`). The `plt.show()` doesn't look use the lists at all. Move all the plot code to the `showPlot` method, or provide the data as an argument to `__init__`.

Note that plt.show(), plt.title() etc. implicitely use the "current" axis; this could be a different plot made elsewhere. Use for example `self.ax.set_title`.

Depending on what you're trying to do with `world`, it may be best to

```
def __init__(self, X, Y, Z):
    self.X, self.Y, self.Z = X, Y, Z

def createPlot(self):
    self.fig = plt.figure()
    ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
    ... # do the plotting
    return ax
```

and use with:

```
earth = world(X, Y, Z)
earth.createPlot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I changed my code to include all X,Y,Z values in the __init__ part and everything plotting-related to a specific defined function and it worked indeed!